# Loop coordinates of intesected line and an outline - R

Tags: r

Based on this answer [How to get the coordinates of an intesected line with an outline - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354966/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-an-intesected-line-with-an-outline-r) ,I tried to run a loop using the script below. Any idea why I can not plot all the intersection points and lines? The shape is different than the answer given

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
  
t <- seq(0, 2*pi, by=0.1)
df <- data.frame(x = 13*sin(t)^3,
                 y = 4*cos(t)-2*cos(3*t)-5*cos(4*t)-cos(2*t))
df <- rbind(df, df[1,]) # close the polygon
 
meanX <- mean(df$x)
meanY <- mean(df$y)
 
# Transform your data.frame in a sf polygon (the first and last points
# must have the same coordinates)
 
#> Linking to GEOS 3.5.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.2
poly <- st_sf(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(as.matrix(df)))))

# Choose the angle (in degrees)
rotAngles <- 5

for(angle in seq(0,359,rotAngles)) {
  
# Find the minimum length for the line segment to be always 
# outside the cloud whatever the choosen angle
maxX <- max(abs(abs(df[,"x"]) - abs(meanX)))
maxY <- max(abs(abs(df[,"y"]) - abs(meanY)))
line_length = sqrt(maxX^2 + maxY^2) + 1

# Find the coordinates of the 2 points to draw a line with 
# the intended angle.
# This is the gray line on the graph below
line <- rbind(c(meanX,meanY), 
              c(meanX + line_length * cos((pi/180)*angle), 
                meanY + line_length * sin((pi/180)*angle)))
# Transform into a sf line object
line <- st_sf(st_sfc(st_linestring(line)))

# Intersect the polygon and line. The result is a two points line
# shown in black on the plot below
intersect_line <- st_intersection(poly, line)

# Extract only the second point of this line.
# This is the intersecting point
intersect_point <- st_coordinates(intersect_line)[2,c("X","Y")] 

# Visualise this with ggplot and without geom_sf

# you need first transform back the lines into data.frame
line <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(line))[,1:2]
intersect_line <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(intersect_line))[,1:2]


ggplot() + geom_path(data=df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line(data=line, aes(x = X, y = Y), color = "gray80", lwd = 3) + 
  geom_line(data=intersect_line, aes(x = X, y = Y), color = "gray20", lwd = 1) + 
  geom_point(aes(meanX, meanY), colour="orangered", size=2) +
  geom_point(aes(intersect_point["X"], intersect_point["Y"]), 
             colour="orangered", size=2) +
  theme_bw()
}
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen wrapping the one polygon, one line code into a one polygon, 71 line loop? You've made no provision for tracking iterations LHS <- RHS, which generally would look like LHS[i] <- RHS[i], all the way down through plotting, unless you just want the last.

Comment: Thanks but where shell I put the [angle]. Furthermore, can I store all the intersection points in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we'll go back to @Gilles polygon shape as it is more consistent with his reasoning and presentation:

```
# Generate a heart shape

t <- seq(0, 2*pi, by=0.1)
df <- data.frame(x = 16*sin(t)^3, 
                 y = 13*cos(t)-5*cos(2*t)-2*cos(3*t)-cos(4*t))
df <- rbind(df, df[1,]) # close the polygon

meanX <- mean(df$x)
meanY <- mean(df$y)

library(sf)
poly <- st_sf(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(as.matrix(df)))))
```

These elements don't change and don't need to calculated multiple times inside a loop:

```
maxX <- max(abs(abs(df[,"x"]) - abs(meanX)))
maxY <- max(abs(abs(df[,"y"]) - abs(meanY)))
line_length = sqrt(maxX^2 + maxY^2) + 1
```

Then your rotAngle and angle:

```
rotAngle <- 5
angle <- seq(0, 359, rotAngle)
```

Focusing attention on the `for` loop, the first `line` call has elements that do and don't change. Let's make an empty list to hold our results, made outside the for loop, that will hold 2x2 matrices:

```
line_lst <- list()

for (j in 1:length(angle)) {
line_lst[[j]] <- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol=2)
line_lst[[j]][1,1] <- meanX
line_lst[[j]][1,2] <- meanY
line_lst[[j]][2,1] <- meanX + line_length * cos((pi/180)*angle[j])
 line_lst[[j]][2,2] <- meanY + line_length * sin((pi/180)*angle[j])
 }

line_lst[[1]]
             [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 1.225402e-06 0.09131118
[2,] 2.425684e+01 0.09131118

line_lst[[72]]
             [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 1.225402e-06  0.09131118
[2,] 2.416454e+01 -2.02281169
```

Those seem reasonable, and this was mainly what I wanted to show, explicating on the LHS[j] <- RHS[j], with the which iteration we're on in 1:length(angle). And on to linestring, intersection, and points,
same make an empty receiver, loop thru:

```
# here we have mismatch of establishing an `i` counter then
# counting `j`, which look close enough to tired eyes
# this will result in NULL(s)
linestring_lst <- list()
for (i in 1:length(line_lst)) { # this causes future error
linestring_lst[[j]] <- st_sf(st_sfc(st_linestring(line_lst[[j]]))) 
}

# simply keeping our accounting right, using all `i` or all `j`,
# or staying away from things that look alike and using `k` here

for (k in 1:length(line_lst)) { 
linestring_lst[[k]] <- st_sf(st_sfc(st_linestring(line_lst[[k]]))) 
}

intersection_lst <- list()
for (j in 1:length(linestring_lst)) {
intersection_lst[[j]] <- st_intersection(poly, linestring_lst[[j]])
}

intersect_points <- list()
for (j in 1:length(intersection_lst)) {
intersect_points[[j]] <- st_coordinates(intersection_lst[[j]])[2,c('X','Y')]
}
```

The things to remember here related to for loops, create your receiver objects outside the loop, index both the LHS[j] and RHS[j] (`[` for vector-like receivers, `[[` for lists). And having done each of these independently, you can put it all in one for loop.

And final step, take the lists to data.frame(s) for use in ggplot.

```
intersect_pts_df <- as.data.frame(do.call('rbind', intersect_points))
head(intersect_pts_df, n = 3)
         X          Y
1 14.96993 0.09131118
2 15.56797 1.45333163
3 15.87039 2.88968964
```

Comment: How do you perform the intersection points between the loop lines *(meanX, meanY, meanX + line_length * cos((pi/180)*angle[j]), meanY + line_length * sin((pi/180)*angle[j]))* and the heart shape.

Comment: Sketched out above.

Comment: Any idea why I get this error: Error in UseMethod("st_intersection") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "function"?

Comment: What is returned from `class(poly)` and `class(intersection_lst)`, but something is a function rather than the result of a function that st_intersection can work with. Where'd it come up for you? And you can get the highlighting you want by putting phrases or words between '`' backticks.

Comment: class(poly) is a "function" and class(intersection_lst) is a "list". I do not see that you declared poly in your script

Comment: You're right, thanks for checking, forgot to bring that across from @johnsal, and picked up as function from attached pkgs. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get this error: > for (j in 1:length(linestring_lst)) {
+   intersection_lst[[j]] <- st_intersection(poly, linestring_lst[[j]])
+ }    
  *Error in UseMethod("st_geometry") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_geometry' applied to an object of class "NULL"*

Comment: I got that Error in UseMethod("st_geometry") when I had a mismatch of for (j in 1:length(linestring_lst)) { + intersection_lst[[i]], 'j' outside and 'i' inside the loop in my case, though you appear to have j(s) throughout? No, that was the prior, linestring_lst creation that was NULL for the mismatch, then returned Error in st_intersection due to NULL input. Yes, went down that rabbit hole too!

Comment: I still do not get it. As rotAngle <- 5 there should always be intersection points

Comment: Edited with comments where my bad copy/pasting led you astray. Appears to work now...